# $g$ is an identification

Tags: general-topology

Definition:
A continuous surjection

$f:X\longrightarrow Y$

is an identification

if a subset $U$ of $Y$
is open

if and only if

$f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Problem:
Let $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be
is an identification,and let
$g:Y\longrightarrow Z$ be
a continuous surjection.
Prove that:
$g$ is an identification
if and only if
$gf$ is an identification.

Comment: You should show your work first and where you get trouble.

Comment: Due to an absence of research efforts of the asker, I [mark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3838767/71850) the question answered and vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

To make the question answered I note that the proof easily follows from the definitions of continuous maps and identifications (usually called quotient maps), see Corollaries 2.4.4 and 2.4.5 from “General topology” by Ryszard Engelking (Heldermann Verlag, Berlin, 1989).